# Azure Devops: mark a package in the artifact feed as 'Release'

Tags: azure-devops, nuget-package, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-artifacts

How do you mark an artifact as 'Release' in the artifact feed? I have a pipeline that uses the NuGet packages and creates binary files. I also have a release pipeline that consumes the binary files. The release pipeline just has an empty job for now. I ran a deployment. The artifacts are still just marked as 'Local'. I'd like to mark the artifacts as 'Release' for additional protection from accidental deletion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your description, you would need to change the NuGet package pushed to Azure Artifacts feed with the view of `Release` rather than `Local`.

Kindly be noted that, Azure Artifacts only supports publishing and restoring packages from and to the default view - @Local.

According to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/concepts/views?view=azure-devops), All Artifacts feeds come with three views: `@local`, `@prerelease`, and `@release`. The latter two are suggested views that you can rename or delete as desired. `@local` is the default view that's commonly used in upstream sources.

If you prefer to use packages in `@release` view, please promote the selected version(s) of your package under `@release` and then you can consume them as release pipeline artifacts by selecting `@release` view.

[image]

Comment: You said that Azure DevOps only supports restoring artifacts from the @local feed view. Does this mean that if I promote a package to 'release' the pipeline will no longer be able to use it because the NuGet restore step will fail?

Comment: Hi @CBFT, taking the screenshot above for example, after we promote the package to `@release`, we can see the specific versions of packages are marked with both `Local` and `Release`. Hence they should be able to restore from `@local` view.